# Materials not properly loading during rendering

Tags: rendering, materials

When I try to render an object the material won't show properly. The first image is what it looks like in viewport/preview render, the second one is when it is rendered.

[image: Pre-Render/Viewport/Preview-Render]

[image: Render]

Comment: it looks like you still have objects enable for render (check your Outliner settings)

Comment: Where do i find that?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead. See [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org), so we don't have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges, a hardware issue such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.

Comment: It's clear enough to tell what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem probably comes from the render activation of these objects, just disable the camera icons:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This worked.